# Firebase - return user uid and set user meta data value to different node

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from a Users node in Firebase and use the retrieved data in a set() to another node. Specifically I want to use my user UID to look at which "branch" the user belongs to and then use the value in the set()

I have the following snapshot to get the "branch" of the user. It logs to the console the correct value

```
    var ref = new Firebase("firebase/url");
    var authData = ref.getAuth();
    var userUID = authData.uid
    var userRef = new Firebase("firebase/URL" + userUID);      



 userRef.once("value", userBranch)

     function userBranch(snapshot) {
     var data = snapshot.val();
     console.log(data.branch);
      };
```

With the returned "branch" value I want to use it in the following set()

```
    var postsRef = ref.child("Posts");
    var newPostRef = postsRef.push();
    var postID = newPostRef.key();


    postsRef.child(postID).set({
         branch: data.branch})
```

What is the best way to take the value out of the function userBranch so I can use it in my set()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `.once` a little bit wrong, but you have the right idea.

```
var ref = new Firebase("firebase/url");
var authData = ref.getAuth();
var userUID = authData.uid
var userRef = new Firebase("firebase/URL" + userUID);      

// Second parameter is callback function that receives data (snapshot)
userRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {)
    var data = snapshot.val();
    console.log(data.branch);
    // Save value at data.branch
    var dataBranch = data.branch;

    var postsRef = ref.child("Posts");
    var newPostRef = postsRef.push();
    var postID = newPostRef.key();

    // Save it, erasing all previous data at location
    postsRef.child(postID).set({
        "branch": dataBranch
    });

};
```

You were a little mixed up with the second parameter for `.once`.

References:

[Firebase | .push](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/push.html)

[Firebase | .once](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/once.html)

[Firebase | .set](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/set.html)